# How to export a large table in csv format with 8 millions rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, cmd, phpmyadmin, xampp

I tried to export my table in csv format through phpmyadmin but it contains 8 millions rows so my local server stops itself after rendering browser for a long time without giving my result. So, I am wanting for a solution to convert those data into csv format.

Comment: What else have you tried? Why not write a program to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with Select OUTFILE?

The solution:

```
SELECT 
    orderNumber, status, orderDate, requiredDate, comments
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    status = 'Cancelled' 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/cancelled_orders.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```